# Junk character in MySQL DB after it exceeds a specified range of character for a particular column

Tags: mysql

When I try to update my MySQL DB for values with 'Russian characters' then junk character appears like '&#! 1076;уем ' . 
This junk character comes when the characters in a line exceeds a specified limit of 364 bytes. Upon appending \r\n before the word removes junk character from the line. 
This solution seems to work fine when I use MSSQL but in case of MySQL if DB is already created and I run my update scripts to include \r\n before a word reaches 364 bytes for a particular column then still the junk character appears.

Kindly advice and let me know if more info is required on the above statement.

Comment: what is the character set for the table? make sure it is utf8

Comment: Yaa, it's UTF8.

Comment: what about "character_set_server"? run SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character\_set\_%'; and find out

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is resolved by appending "\r\n" instead of "\r\n" before the specified character limit in MySQL DB . 
No more junk character appears.

Thankyou all :-)